# How to transition a coin to the middle of the screen then up when collecting it?

Tags: unity, animation

I have a **coin** sprite that [animates spinning in place, like this](https://i.giphy.com/media/Lkcl45qfo6sq8YkLvd/giphy.webp).

When the player picks up the coin, I want to make a transition while keeping the animation. First moving towards middle, then much faster all the way up until it leaves the screen like this:

[image: Sketch of coin transition]

My question: Is this done mostly via adjusting the Transform component component via scripting? Or are games implementing something like this in a different way?

Comment: Games probably implement this in every different way you or I can imagine, and several ways neither of us can. But that doesn't matter. What matters is whether *your* implementation is serving your needs. It sounds like you have an idea for how to accomplish this using the transform component. How have you tried doing that so far, and how do the results compare against your goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the coin always starts out in the same place (bottom-right corner of the screen in your example), you can do everything with animations. For example, you could use a separate animation on the coin's *parent* to move the coin to the center of the screen and then upward.

If the coin might start out anywhere on the screen, I would suggest animating the movement (to center-screen and then up) using a coroutine instead of a keyframe animation. E.g.:

```
private IEnumerator CollectCoin() {
    Vector3 start = coin.transform.position;
    Camera camera = Camera.main;
    Vector3 screenCenterPos = new Vector3(camera.pixelWidth / 2, camera.pixelHeight / 2, 10);
    Vector3 end = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenCenterPos);

    //fly to center of screen
    float duration = 1; //adjust as needed
    float elapsed = 0;
    while (elapsed < duration) {
        yield return null;
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        float t = elapsed / duration;
        coin.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, t);
    }

    //fly up
    start = end;
    end.y += 5; //adjust as needed
    duration = .5f; //adjust as needed
    elapsed = 0;
    while (elapsed < duration) {
        yield return null;
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        float t = elapsed / duration;
        coin.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, t);
    }
}
```

The above will do simple linear animations. If you would prefer to incorporate easing, you can use a tween library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code and it works just as expected. One small detail in case someone else copies it to achieve this functionality - at the beginning it's camera.ScreenToWorldPoint. I also experimented with a Tween library (doTween) and I want to say that I had no idea such libraries were around. Managed to implement the same functionality with it. I will take a look tomorrow on how to use the father object animation - just for science. Again, thanks a bunch for your detailed answer @Kevin

Comment: @Stefan Glad to help! Thanks for letting me know about the mistake in the function name, I fixed it.